# Disable submit button when user clicks it on mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to disable a button when user clicks it. I could it, but I think my way was not good.
my way:

I set `ViewBag.IsSaveButtonDisabled` to `true` and check this container div by javascript then I disabled the save button. I know, it's bad solution. I want to control my submit button's disabled property on the sever side.

What is the best practice for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new property to yourViewModel

Model

```
viewModel{
    ...
    public string IsDisabled{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    viewModel model = new viewModel { ... , IsDisabled = "disabled"};
    return View(model);
}
```

And in your View

```
@model viewModel
<input type="submit" value="Kaydet" @Model.IsDisabled/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set your `ViewData["IsEnabled"]` to false/true in your controller and return to view.

```
public ActionResult ButtonEvent()
{
    ViewData["IsEnabled"]=false;
    // ... do something
    ViewData["IsEnabled"]=true;
    return View();
}
```

In your `jQuery`, use this `ViewData["IsEnabled"]` to disable the button:

```
$(function(){
    if(!@ViewData["IsEnabled"]){
        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, i didnt noticed that the answer is accepted while i'm posting a solution to this

Comment: @KarthikChintala No worries - on SO, having many answers is the point. :)